# Data in an array on a NodeJs server

Tags: node.js, arrays, storage, storing-data

I have an array on the node js server file which holds some static data which will be used again and again. My question is, will that data remain the same for all the users or every user will get an empty array at first?

`I am guessing that the array will be the same for all the users since it's on the server and the server will not change`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just storing the array in a regular old variable and your server inspects that variable for every request, then all users will see the same data.

Comment: Yeah, my server is gonna inspect that same variable each time a request will be made to a specific endpoint by different users. And does that mean that the data will remain in the array as long as my server doesn't restart?

Comment: Thanks, Fred for the help.